# How to make Custom Navigation control drawer (slider) using IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have code using Extra Library.
but i want to own navigation control without any library.
so how it possible in IOS (Objective-C)?

For Example:

> SWRevealViewController

Answer (score 0):

No default iOS sliding control in iOS we can either use these third party library or code own.

Comment: @kalpeshsatasiya. own means write whole library. why you don't use that too easy library. Check http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

Comment: @kalpeshsatasiya. Could you accept answer by clicking check button?